# Join BIRT Rowdata with XML Datasource

Tags: xml, join, datasource, birt

I have a BIRT-report with data from a normal database. But I need additional data from an xml source (URL), which need a parameter from the data row. It is a small extract from a large xml source fetched by id, so I must load the xml row by row.

What is the best way to fetch additional xml data with url-parameters build from row data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution by my own

1. Define scripted datasource
2. Define scripted dataset of datasource
3. Define output columns
4. Define id as parameter
5. Join dataset on report with main by id
6. Create a java class of ScriptedDataSetEventAdapter, override the fetch method an get the id with dataSet.getInputParameters()
7. Call data with standard java technology